# Entity Framework как отключить кэширование получаемых данных?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Есть контекст. Он создается, когда я открываю форму и живет до ее закрытия. Я запрашиваю данные по определенному сету, меняю в них кое что, сохраняю. Форму не закрываю, контекст все еще жив. Теперь я меняю одно из полей прямо в базе (через стороннюю программу). Обновляю данные на своей форме (снова получаю `context.ConcreteSet'), но внесенные извне изменения не подхватываются. То есть контекст где то кеширует получаемые данные. Но мне в данном случае это не нужно, потому что точно так же я могу изменить данные в другом экземпляре контекста, но в первом они так же не подтянутся. Короче надо сделать запрос заново. Как?

Comment: создавайте один контекст на одну бизнес-операцию, а не держите один общий контекст на приложение

Comment: @PashaPash, тогда скажите. Вот запросил я набор данных. Сделал это в специально созданном контексте. Дальше требуется изменить один из Entity. Я передаю его в форму для редактирования. Редактирую его, нажимаю сохранить, что при этом должно произойти? `context.SaveChanged()` я уже выполнить не могу, потому что контекста нет, нужно создавать новый. Ну допустим тут не сложно, выполнить UpdateOrInsert(). Но что делать, чтобы можно  было редактировать элементы прямо в таблице на форме? Ведь контекста нет, значит он за изменениями следить не будет уже.